# Why do I have an infinite recursion loop happening with these symlinks

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, symlink, gruntjs

I'm using node to build some jQuery plugins. The tests for each one run using grunt and qunit and include copies of jQuery from a shared directory which is above (i.e. outside of) the grunt server's web root for each one.

```
/plug1 //web root for plug2's server
  /libs
    /jquery
  /tests
/plug2 //web root for plug2's server
  /libs
    /jquery
  /tests
/jquery
  jquery-1.9.0.js
   ...
  jquery-1.5.0.js
```

So I'm trying to use symlinks in order to include jQuery in the tests

```
ln -s ../jquery/* libs/jquery
```

but when I run my tests task (which runs the tests once for each version of jQuery by writing a script tag for the right version after reading the version number from the page's query string) I get the following errors

```
Running "qunit:urls" (qunit) task
Testing test.html?jquery=1.5.0Error: ELOOP, stat '/Users/me/Sites/opensource/jquery/plug1/libs/jquery/jquery-1.5.js'
```

I'm relatively new to Unix, but I guess this means there's some infinite recursion error or similar.

Is there a way I can get node/grunt to use symlinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run ln from the jquery directory.

```
cd plugs1/libs/jquery
ln -s ../../jquery/* .

cd ../../plugs2/libs/jquery
ln -s ../../jquery/* .
```